# How to space out tall in page setup scaling option in Excel through Perl

Tags: excel, perl

Is there a way to fit to 1 page(s) wide only (tall should be blank) in excel through perl, so that we can set the scaling as "Fit All Columns on One Page". Same as below.

Tried **"$worksheet1->fit_to_pages( 1, 0 );"**, but it is changing to 1,1 (1-wide & 1-tall).

[image]

Comment: You should add (at least) which module do you using...

Comment: we use Excel::Writer::XLSX

Comment: @jm66 - Any comments or suggestions on the above?

Comment: Double check your code, because probably you somewhere using the `(1,1)`. The module works correctly and on my Mac Excel it is OK - exactly as you want.

Comment: @jm66 - i have checked the code again, am using (1,0) only. is der any other alternate command on the same module?

Answer (score 0):

See, you didn't provided any code. Therefore nobody could help you. The module works correctly. Demo:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'test.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$worksheet->write( 0, 0, "Hi" );
$worksheet->fit_to_pages(1,0);
```

Now after opening it in my Excel, it shows:

[image]

or in the PageSetup

[image]

Even if you check the `xml` in the `xlsx` (e.g. rename the `.xlsx` to `.zip` and unzip) you will find in the `sheet.xml` the following snipet:

```
<pageSetup fitToHeight="0" orientation="portrait"/>
```

as you can see, the content of the generated `.xlsx` file is correctly set the `fitToHeight` (aka "tall") to `0`.

So, the problem - as I said in the comment - is in your side.